# Updating plant/crop database

Tags: hydrology, models, water

I have been trying to update the QSWAT+ crop database to include new crops. However it seems the model refuses to read a look-up table with new crops leaving me unable to represent all the various crops that I have in my study area. This is with regards to the first stage where HRU delineation is performed

To work around this, I create the HRUs  using a look-up table with codes for crops accepted by SWAT+ and then later I create a record of my crop in the QSWAT+ editor under the plant database and link to the wrong record.

I would like to know how to make QSWAT+ accept a look-up table (and a plant database) with new crops (as it does in SWAT2012) in the initial HRU delineation step.